# How to implement the Django query-filter expression API's kwarg syntax (e.g. `related_model__fieldname__condition`)?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-models

I'm working on a Django app that needs to perform operations on specified model fields.

Django already has a calling style for referencing model fields with query constraints -- multiple terms are composed into predicates with double-underscores and passed as keyword args. Queryset filtering, using `QuerySet.filter()` and `Q()`, make use of this syntax e.g.:

```
stuff = MyStuff.objects.filter(name__isnull=False)
thing = MyStuff.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains="yo") & Q(ptype__iendswith="dogg")).get()
```

The same syntax is used by `F()` expressions, which are used to build dynamic predicates in query statements. The majority Django users have seen (if not used) this syntax in some form.

I would like to create a similar dynamically-evaluated, composeable Python idiom -- for this question's sake I'll call it `G()` -- that uses the same syntax, to furnish a similar handle for a lazily-evaluated field lookup instance that can be logically recombined with other such instances.

How ought one approach this task? Both `Q()` and `F()` are subclasses of `django.utils.tree.Node` -- at least they are in Django 1.4 (they weren't always implemented as they are now, and their interface may or may not be private). Much of the kwarg-filter-expression action takes place in `django.db.models.sql.Query`, I believe... which that is an enormous and daunting class with illegible couplings to myriad bits of the ORM's guts.

I'm reasonably sure the query-filter syntax can be accomplished much more simply than I'm imagining. Where should I begin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. Is it just how to accept arbitrary underscore-separated arguments? Or how to turn those into filters?

Comment: What types of operations are you trying to perform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with the double-underscored-keywords, but the simplest place to start would probably be here:

```
>>> def G(**kwargs):
...     for key, value in kwargs.items():
...         print "{} = {}".format(key.split("__"), value)
...         
...     
... 
>>> G(some__key__here="val1", another__one__again="val2")
['some', 'key', 'here'] = val1
['another', 'one', 'again'] = val2
```

From there, I guess it depends on what you're going to do with that information. Hope this helps!